# python binary format or ascii format

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles

I am working on a python program that takes a big file (+500 MB) and breaks it in half, preserving it's internal syntax.  The file should be ASCII, and it's internal format is character-delimited with no newlines.

When I read the file like this:

```
with open(s3_dest, 'r') as f:
    # read chars from file until breakByte, write them to topString
    topString = f.read(breakByte)

    offset = breakByte
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        offset += 1
        if not c: 
            break
        topString += c
        buffer += c
        print(f"[%s] Buffer: %s", offset, buffer)
        if pattern.match(buffer):
            # last chunk was transaction end!
            break
        if c == delimiter:
            buffer = ''
```

I get an error at execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//./main.py", line 205, in <module>
    topString = f.read(breakByte)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 14050657: invalid start byte
```

(that byte at position 14050657 is hex 3669, or binary 0011011001101001)

When I read the file in binary format, I get these string buffers filled with binary digits, and they look like this:

```
b's'b'i'b'n'b'e'b's'b's'b'.'b'~'b'C'b'R'b'~'b'P'b'K'b'G'b'2'b'|'b'C'b'D'b'3'b'~'b'~'b'~'
```

I understand this is a List of binary digits.  My question is, 1.) if I want to compare them to, say, a regex, like this:

```
pattern = re.compile("^SE~\d{2}~\d{8}$")
[....]
if pattern.match(buffer):
```

how does this work?  It doesn't seem to capture the match.  Also, I compare the delimiter:

```
if str(c) == delimiter:
```

That doesn't work.

I'm confused how to read a file in binary format, but compare the content to strings.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: from the error message and without any other information, it seems you have a corrupted file or at least a character the utf-8 codec cannot decode.  I am unsure what you expect to happen when you read the file in binary.  Please clarify what you are trying to do and if possible provide a sample set of data which exhibits this error.

Comment: Your file isn't ASCII if it has a 0x9b in it.  ASCII is 0x00-0x7F.  You either want binary mode or some other encoding that you have to determine.  You can use the `encoding` parameter of `open` to choose.

Comment: You can print a byte string in hex so `b's'` prints as `73` instead (the hexadecimal value of ASCII `s`).  Use `b's'.hex()`

Comment: Match binary strings with binary patterns and use raw strings with regex, e.g. `re.match(rb'^SE~\d{2}~\d{8}$', b'SE~00~00000000')`

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks so much for your kind attention!  OK I converted the match pattern to bytes, but now when I compare, it gives an error:

    [214240785] Buffer: b's'
        if pattern.match(buffer):
    TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object

note, it prints out as b's'.  Isn't that a byte?

Comment: Would have to see the code that reproduces the problem. Edit the question.